# integrating xoauth.py script into my webapp

Tags: oauth, gmail-imap

I'm integrating [xoauth.py](http://google-mail-xoauth-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/xoauth.py) script from google into my django application because I need to access users Gmail messages from my applications. My intention is to create a key/secret pair once the user intents to access this feature and store the authorization token for latter use.
This is a two step operation: get the validation URL (where the user gets a verification code) and get the authorization token. The second step fails for me with the following message:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/authorization_token?user=iferca@ecoresol.com&code=ycH19iaufCHoJ7APVkBGe_Hu&key=4/nj5s6sLBx-DKWUYJlUzERnngOO_6&token=wwvSU3ws448HR1gqiN7NxTh7

Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/iferca/devel/gmail/workspace/imapsrv/imapsrv/../imapsrv/gdg/views.py" in request_authoization_token
  27.     response = xoauth.generateAuthorizationTokenFromVerificationCode(user, code,         request_key, request_secret)
File "/Users/iferca/devel/gmail/workspace/imapsrv/imapsrv/../imapsrv/gdg/xoauth.py" in generateAuthorizationTokenFromVerificationCode
  512.         google_accounts_url_generator)
File "/Users/iferca/devel/gmail/workspace/imapsrv/imapsrv/../imapsrv/gdg/xoauth.py" in    GetAccessToken
  316.                                      request_token.secret)
File "/Users/iferca/devel/gmail/workspace/imapsrv/imapsrv/../imapsrv/gdg/xoauth.py" in GenerateOauthSignature
  200.   return GenerateHmacSha1Signature(base_string, key)
File "/Users/iferca/devel/gmail/workspace/imapsrv/imapsrv/../imapsrv/gdg/xoauth.py" in GenerateHmacSha1Signature
  194.   digest = hmac.new(key, text, hashlib.sha1)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hmac.py" in new
  133.     return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hmac.py" in __init__
  72.         self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))

Exception Type: TypeError at /authorization_token
Exception Value: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

The same script runs well in the command line. I even tested the line that throws the error by hand using python console and I can't reproduce the error, as follows:

```
>>> key = "anonymous&wwvSU3ws448HR1gqiN7NxTh7"
>>> trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
>>> trans_5C
'\\]^_XYZ[TUVWPQRSLMNOHIJKDEFG@ABC|}~\x7fxyz{tuvwpqrslmnohijkdefg`abc\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x14\x15\x16\x17\x10\x11\x12\x13\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x08\t\n\x0b\x04\x05\x06\x07\x00\x01\x02\x03<=>?89:;45670123,-./()*+$%&\' !"#\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xec\xed\xee\xef\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x94\x95\x96\x97\x90\x91\x92\x93\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x84\x85\x86\x87\x80\x81\x82\x83\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3'
>>> key.translate(trans_5C)
'=232%13)/z++*\x0f\to+/hhd\x14\x0em;-5\x12k\x12$\x084k'
```

I added two functions to the script to be used by my web application as interface for the two steps, the functions are as follows:

```
def requestTokenVerificationURL(user):
    if not user:
        raise Exception('requestTokenVerificationURL invoked without user argument')
    scope = 'https://mail.google.com/'
    nonce = None
    timestamp = None
    consumer_key = 'anonymous'
    consumer_secret = 'anonymous'
    consumer = OAuthEntity(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    google_accounts_url_generator = GoogleAccountsUrlGenerator(user)
    authurl_token = GenerateRequestTokenAndAuthorizationURL(consumer, scope, nonce,
        timestamp, google_accounts_url_generator)
    return {'request_token_key': authurl_token['token'].key,
            'request_token_secret': authurl_token['token'].secret,
            'authorization_url': authurl_token['authorization_url'].strip()}


def generateAuthorizationTokenFromVerificationCode(user, verificationCode, request_key, request_secret):
    consumer_key = 'anonymous'
    consumer_secret = 'anonymous'
    consumer = OAuthEntity(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    request_token = OAuthEntity(request_key, request_secret)
    google_accounts_url_generator = GoogleAccountsUrlGenerator(user)
    access_token = GetAccessToken(consumer, request_token, verificationCode,
        google_accounts_url_generator)
    return access_token
```

Any hit will be appreciated, thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem!

The issue was related with the fact that the request token and secret are passed to the client back and forth and in the process of getting it form the GET or POST request django returns a unicode instead of a string (str). The issue was solved by converting unicode to string the request token/secret before passing them to the xoauth.py functions.

Hope this will save 3 days of testing to someone else!